# Grails and background tasks

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm, executorservice

User fills some form where he sets parameters for report generation. He submits the form, server validates the parameters, returns message that everything is ok to the user and generates the report. After report generation is finished, user gets email with link to report.

What is the proper way to achieve this in grails?
At the moment I have a service that generates the report, it looks like this:

```
@Transactional
class AnalyticsService {

    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()

    def buildExportAndSendMail() {
        executor.execute {
            //GENERATE REPORT AND SEND MAIL. USES GORM.
        }
    }

    @PreDestroy
    void shutdown() {
        executor.shutdownNow()
    }
}
```

My controller action looks like this:

```
def generateReport(ReportParams command) {
    if(!command.hasErrors()) {
        analyticsService.buildExportAndSendMail()
        render([success:true, html:"Your report is being generated."] as JSON)
    } else {
        ...
    }
}
```

However, service is throwing an error when trying to acces domain object fields:

```
Exception in thread "pool-8-thread-1" 
Error |
org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy - no Session
```

What would be a proper way for doing this in grails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that you are creating a new thread and it's not bound to a Hibernate session. Creating one is easy enough. It doesn't matter what domain class you use. For example:

```
def buildExportAndSendMail() {
  executor.execute {
    SomeDomainClass.withNewSession { session ->
      //GENERATE REPORT AND SEND MAIL. USES GORM.
    }
  }
}
```

You can read more about `withNewSession` in the [documentation](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/withNewSession.html).

Comment: You are right, it works. I also had to re-attach some objects with obj.attach() (they were acquired in previous session). Thanks.

Comment: Even though you have selected this as the solution, you really should read section 10 of the Guide - Asynchronous Programming.  While you have successfully created a new hibernate session, you should probably be using the Grails asynchronous execution support as you get all of the artefact injection and hibernate session support for free. If you want to do something scheduled, then the Quartz plugin (as suggested in another response) is the right way to go.

Comment: @SteveHole It's good to point out other options, and what works best really depends on the requirements. The async/gpars approach is obviously very powerful (and something I would prefer personally), but this very specific question as using another approach.

Answer (score 1):

I would probably add a job with the grails [quartz plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/quartz):

```
class ReportJob {
    def execute () {
        // create report
        // mail report
    }
}
```

and then trigger the job with

```
ReportJob.triggerNow (Map params)
```

Advantage is, that you don't need to explicitly handle threading or session stuff.

Comment: Yes, that could work too. Another option: http://gpc.github.io/grails-jms/docs/manual/index.html